# Android, передать данные из custom list item в другой активити

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Совсем недавно начал изучать android. Необходимо передать данные (string ссылку на изображение, string id, string username) из listItem'a в другой активити. Как это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `intent`

*Отправляем*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("url", "img url");
startActivity(intent);
```

*Достаем*

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra("url");
```

А вообще [вот](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent.html) почитайте.

[Достать данные из listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988761/how-to-get-string-from-listview)

Comment: Да, про putExtra() я знаю, так вот как мне достать этот самый url из выбранного listItem'a?

Comment: Он же у вас где-то хранится? В массиве например?

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо

Comment: Я добавил ссылку, посмотрите, там про то как достать из listview.