# Как записать в переменную позицию нажатого элемента recyclerview?

Tags: android, recyclerview

В адаптере такой код загружает картинку и обрабатывает нажатие на элемент

```
Recyclerview
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Book book = booksList.get(position);
         //* Загрузка обложки из интернета. Ссылки берем из ParseTask (через MainActivity)
        Picasso
                .with(holder.imgObl.getContext())
                .load(book.getUrls())
                .into(holder.imgObl);

        holder.imgObl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(holder.imgObl.getContext(),
//                "Пойдем читать ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(holder.imgObl.getContext(), SliderActivity.class);
                holder.imgObl.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как узнать позицию нажатого элемента Recyclerview и записать в переменную, доступную к использованию в методах другого класса?

Comment: Как вы хотите использовать позицию в других классах?

Comment: По номеру нажатого элемента я буду создавать экземпляр класса Book с перечнем имён файлов рисунков

Comment: позиция нажатого пункта это где int pisition, position  и есть номер пункта. А насчёт записи в переменную не совсем понятно, скажите в общем чего хотите добиться?

Comment: Идея приложения - это иллюстрации сказок с озвучкой. Recyclerview - это список книг с обложками. При нажатии на любую из них - переход в активность, где будут показываться иллюстрации и воспроизводиться звук. То есть мне нужно знать позицию нажатого элемента, чтобы подставлять для показа нужные картинки и звуки из памяти

Comment: про position я понял, но у меня не получается использовать его из другого класса

Comment: В другую Activity нужно передавать через intent: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556943/11515

Comment: woesss, ваш комментарий помог, все получилось. Напишите его как ответ, я помечу решением. Спасибо!